# How do I accept an Option<String>, process it, and return an Option<String>?

Tags: rust

Coming from Python, I am having some trouble grasping lifetimes. I am trying to implement this trivial function to return an `Option<String>` but I can not get it. All I have been able to do so far is:

```
fn match_exception(exception: Option<String>) -> String {
    let piles = ["a", "b"];
    exception
        .unwrap_or("".to_string())
        .split(',')
        .map(|exc| exc.trim())
        .filter(|exc| piles.contains(exc))
        .next()
        .unwrap_or("")
        .to_string()
}
```

This returns a `String` (not to mention looks super clunky to me) but I was hoping to get it to come back in the same format that it entered, `Option<String>`.

If I remove everything after the `next` call it returns an `Option<&str>` and if I go ahead and redefine my expected return type to `Option<&str>` it complains that I haven't set lifetimes:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/lib.rs:1:57
  |
1 | fn match_exception(exception: Option<String>) -> Option<&str> {
  |                                                         ^ expected lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
  = help: consider giving it an explicit bounded or 'static lifetime
```

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction or explain this in a slightly more simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return `Option<&str>`, the returned `&str` must refer to something that is available after the function returned. Since you pass an `Option<String>` into the function, this value won't be available once the function returned.

If you convert the string slices `to_string`, you can use the following:

```
fn match_exception(exception: Option<String>) -> Option<String> {
    let piles = ["a", "b"];
    exception
        .unwrap_or("".to_string())
        .split(',')
        .map(|exc| exc.trim())
        .filter(|exc| piles.contains(exc))
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .next()
}
```

Note that `|s| s.to_string()` is relatively expensive.

What you actually may want to do is to accept an `Option<&str>` in the first place:

```
fn match_exception(exception: Option<&str>) -> Option<&str> {
    let piles = ["a", "b"];
    exception
        .unwrap_or("")
        .split(',')
        .map(|exc| exc.trim())
        .filter(|exc| piles.contains(exc))
        .next()
}
```

Comment: I didn’t even think about adjusting the input type, pretty silly of me. But thanks, you’re saying that because the output is referencing an input that I consumed within the function, once I exit that scope the reference to that is no longer valid because it was consumed within the function scope?

Comment: @aws_apprentice Correct. If you accept an `Option<String>`, the contained string will go out of scope (is no longer valid) when the function returns.